# Keyboard library event blocks execution

Tags: python, keyboard, barcode

I am trying to transfer data from a barcode scanner to a machine through socket messaging.
At this point the scanner plays no role in the script. It should works with keyboard only.

In the **main** function, I'm waiting for keyboard inputs. If there were some, and a certain amount of time passed (timeout_duration=0.5), the script should pass on the data with the process_barcode() function.
But it never gets to that to that point, even though it reaches the time limit.
Am I too clouded to figure out the syntax issue here?

```
import socket
import keyboard
import time

# TCP/IP server details
server_ip = "10.10.0.0"
server_port = 5200

# Timeout for barcode input in seconds
timeout_duration = 0.5

def send_data(data):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((server_ip, server_port))
        s.sendall(data.encode())

def process_barcode(barcode):
    if ';' in barcode:
        forwarded_data = f"{barcode};1"
    else:
        forwarded_data = f"test;{barcode};1"
    
    send_data(forwarded_data)

def main():
    barcode = ""
    last_key_time = time.time()
    
    print("Waiting for barcode scanner input...")
    
    while True:
        event = keyboard.read_event(suppress=True)
        
        if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
            print(time.time() - last_key_time)
            barcode += event.name
            print(barcode)
            last_key_time = time.time()
        
        # Check for timeout
        if (time.time() - last_key_time > timeout_duration) and barcode:
            # Process the received barcode
            print("success")
            process_barcode(barcode)
            barcode = ""
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When do you expect that `time.time() - last_key_time > timeout_duration` would be true? I think it would only be if you get a KEY_UP event more than 0.5 sec after a KEY_DOWN event, i.e. if a key is held down for 0.5 sec.

Comment: the `keyboard.read_event(suppress=True)` is **blocking** and changing the suppress argument to `False` is also **blocking**, so this method will not work as you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line here:

```
event = keyboard.read_event(suppress=True)
```

The read_event method blocks execution so the following conditionals will only execute when a new key press occurs. Meaning this conditional:

```
if (time.time() - last_key_time > timeout_duration) and barcode:
```

Is only checked after a new key press so last_key_time is overwritten before every check and thus you never have a great enough difference between time.time() and last_key_time to trigger the code following the conditional. You can test this by printing time.time() - last_key_time.

You need to rewrite the code. I refactored your main function to something like this that appears to function as desired:

```
def main():
    barcode = ""
    last_key_time = time.time()
    
    print("Waiting for barcode scanner input...")
    
    keyboard.start_recording()
    old_keys_pressed = []
    while True:
        new_keys_pressed = keyboard.stop_recording()
        keyboard.start_recording()

        if new_keys_pressed != old_keys_pressed:
            print(time.time() - last_key_time)
            barcode += "".join([str(x) for x in new_keys_pressed])
            print(barcode)
            last_key_time = time.time()
        
        # Check for timeout
        if (time.time() - last_key_time > timeout_duration) and barcode:
            # Process the received barcode
            print("success")
            process_barcode(barcode)
            barcode = ""
```

Comment: You might want to filter the contents of `new_keys_pressed` to include only KEY_DOWN events. Otherwise you'll count both the KEY_DOWN and the KEY_UP event for each key.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. The problem was actually this.
I read in the documentation, that events are non blocking. But I must have missed something.
I opted for threading actually. Was easier for me.
Thank you once again.

Comment: @Betterlatethannever,  yes, the event is blocking:  https://pypi.org/project/keyboard

Comment: @D.L Sorry to inquire, but where do you find that information on this link?
What I found is that it specifically states:
"Events automatically captured in separate thread, doesn't block main program."

Comment: @Betterlatethannever https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardread_eventsuppressfalse - *"Blocks until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event"*. I can see the text you quoted, but the point is that the keystroke capture happens on a separate thread so it *can* be non-blocking. However, methods like `read_event()` are intentionally blocking: sometimes that's exactly what you want. If `read_event()` was non-blocking, wouldn't your original code crash? Because presumably you'd expect `read_event()` to return `None` when no event happens, and then `event.event_type` would fail.

Comment: pretty much as @slothrop said.  there are alternative solutions that don't block, but not using the `keyboard` input...  i believe one such method is `import select`.

Comment: The `keyboard` library does let you capture in a non-blocking way: the use of `start_recording()` and `stop_recording()` in this answer is a good example :)